# Question about transient states in markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, examples-counterexamples

Is there a discrete time-homogeneous Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ in which one transient state $i$ satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nf^{(n)}_{ii}=\infty ?$

where $$f_{ii}^{(n)}:=\Pr(X_n=i,X_v\ne i,1\le v\le n-1\mid X_0=i),n\in \mathbb Z^+\quad .$$